# cakephp 2.4: Add quantity with old quantity field

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

In my database table I have a quantity field.I am trying to add new quantities which will add with previous.

I have tried by this code in controller

```
$this->request->data['StoreProduct']['quantity']=100+$this->request->data['StoreProduct']['quantity'];
```

Here this code working fine.But in 100 here I want to place my old data.So at first here I have to sent data which already in database.How can I send this data for add with new data ?

I have sent old data by using find methods, here is the code.

```
$options = array('conditions' => array('StoreProduct.' . $this->StoreProduct->primaryKey => $id));
        $request= $this->StoreProduct->find('all', $options);
```

I have succeed to see the quantity in edit.ctp. Now I can I send this edit.ctp to edit method in controller ?

Comment: Duplicate of hundreds of questios like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773457/cakephp-increment-value

Answer (score 0):

First, get the data using

`$data = $this->StoreProduct->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('StoreProduct.id'=>$id)));`

then add the data

```
$this->request->data['StoreProduct']['quantity']=$data['StoreProduct']['quantity']+$this->request->data['StoreProduct']['quantity'];
```

Comment: @cms what error your are facing while execute this code

Comment: There have no any error, it's taking only input field data.Addition is not working.

Comment: Are you sure you implement the addition correctly. Could you provide your full code for the action.. Edit in your question